# Fast method to read and check 11 million Urls from a text file

Tags: multithreading, performance

We're stress testing one of our environments by trying to see how efficient one of our DNS randomizers work by brute forcing a DNS check from a text file, don't ask, it's one of our engineers' brilliant plan.

The idea has sprung up a bit of a coding challenge in the team and we could not come up with a fast, efficient line of code to get through 11 million records in due time.

Basically, we have a text file containing 11 million derivatives of our randomizer output. We want to read each URL, check if the host can be found and continue if not.

Our initial attempt was to do this in C#, using multi-threading to try and run x-amount of concurrent requests at a time. Based on our calculation, such an approach would take as 3 months to work through the entire file.

We looked at python and calculations points to 6 weeks to work through the same amount of records.

This does not sound correct.

Does any one have an idea of how we can work through all of these records in matter of hours not weeks? Would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: @MarkSetchell predominantly, but nothing stopping us from attempting this on Linux. the team's mostly Windows based and my experience with Unix is somewhat. If you have a solution we could try, I'd be very happy to do so.